# Navigation menu

Tags: javascript

When I take mouse over the Navigation menu links (About Us..), the page moves to left. Is that due to javascript?

[link text](http://www.pinhmct.org/placements.html)

Comment: How is the css around it structured? Is the position fixed? And what is the javascript doing? Did you write it on your own, or did you use the dreamweaver scripts? Edit: Thanks for including link.

Comment: Position is not fixed. It is a drop down menu taken from dynamic drive website

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the **scrollbar** that appears at the browser window's right side. It seems to me that there is a design error causing the content to be much larger with the menu hovered ...

Answer (score 0):

if you hover the menu, the page gets so long that scrollbars occur - and that causes the page to "move to left" (it stays in the center of your viewport, which is what it should do). to fix this, find out whats causing this overflow (the page isn't looking that long, i don't know where the scrollbars come from) or set `overflow-y:scroll` for your body, so there's always a scrollbar (which would be the bad "i don't know what else to do to fix this"-solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the UL dropdown elements away from the bottom of the page or set them to `display:none` until after you've absolutely positioned them at the top of the page. `visibility:hidden` does not take the elemtens out of the flow of the document but just hides them.

A better bet though would be to make them children of the `<a>` tags you already have, so they only need to be displayed rather than displayed and moved.